# SwiftUI getting rid of quotes in a string variable

Tags: swift, string, swiftui

I have a string variable that gets populated from a text field. I want to remove any quotes a user might enter.

I've tried using replacingOccurrences in these examples.

```
print("Test A --------------------")
var testA = "\"Hello\""
var testAtrimmed = testA.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
print(testA)
print(testAtrimmed)
                                    
print("Test B --------------------")
var testB = move.moveAddy
var testBtrimmed = testB.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
print(testB)
print(testBtrimmed)
                                    
print("Test C --------------------")
var testC = String(move.moveAddy)
var testCtrimmed = testC.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
print(testC)
print(testCtrimmed)
```

The output of B and C retain their quotation marks. I've noticed their quotation marks look slightly different. I'm not sure if they are still text somehow but the moveAddy field of my struct is a String.

[here is the console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD6w5.png)

Anything I'm missing? Or any workarounds?

Comment: depending on what the user puts into the text field, there are different forms of quotation marks: https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/quotation-marks/ 
You might want to remove them all.

Comment: Can you show the value of testb and testc before removing quotes in your post or as comment in the code?

Comment: @tail they are is in the console output link photo. I print out both the original value and the value after I try to trim it. Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: Because you casted your original value to String, so I was assuming the original data was in different format/condition than the one you typed in directly to testA which resulted the problem, so I wanted to see the pre-cast data.

Comment: @tail oh I understand what your saying. Me casting it to a String was just an attempt to ensure the value was in fact a String. The output of move.moveAddy is exactly the same as the other testB and testC output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the double quotes offered by Xcode and Device Keyboard are different, you can try this way to ensure that different types of double quotes from these different devices will be removed effectively.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Practice: View {
@State private var test = ""
@State private var test2 = "\"Hello\""
var body: some View {
    TextField("enter", text: $test)
    Button {
        test = test
                .replacing("\u{022}", with: "")
                .replacing("\u{201c}", with: "")
                .replacing("\u{201d}", with: "")
        test2 = test2
                .replacing("\u{022}", with: "")
                .replacing("\u{201c}", with: "")
                .replacing("\u{201d}", with: "")
        print(test)
        print(test2)
    } label: {
        Text("remove")
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. I wasn't aware you could tap into Unicode that way with Strings!